# Use Array Initializers in a Function in Java

Tags: java, arrays, static-methods

I want to write a function which gives me a different int array testArray as an output according to the input I choose. In this example, I want to choose `number = 0`, and get `testArray = {1,2,3,4,5}` as a result. When I give testArray values, I get this error:

`Array constants can only be used in initializers`

```
public class ArrayExample{  
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int number = 0;
        int[] newArray = new int[5];
        newArray = getValues(number);
    }
    

    public static int[] getValues(int number) {
        
        int[] testArray = new int[5];
            
            if(number == 0) {
                testArray  = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
            }
            else if(number == 1) {
                testArray  = {2,3,4,5,6}; 
            }
            else if(number == 2) {
                testArray  = {3,4,5,6,7}; 
            }
            else if(number == 3) {
                testArray  = {4,5,6,7,8}; 
            }       
            else{
                testArray  = {5,6,7,8,9}; 
            }   

            
        return testArray;
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot assign values to an array using the following syntax.

```
int[] newArray = new int[5];
testArray  = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

To solve the issue you can use

```
  testArray  = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this using `Arrays.setAll`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int [] result = getValues(i);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The method

```
public static int[] getValues(int number) {
    int[] array = new int[5];
    Arrays.setAll(array, i->number+i+1);
    return array;
}
```

You could also pass the size of the array as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the error `Array constants can only be used in initializers`.

Valid code

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Wrong code

```
int[] arr;
arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Add the `new int[]` keyword to make the code compileable

```
testArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

But it is better to initialize the array this way using a loop

```
public static int[] getValues(int number) {
    int[] testArray = new int[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        testArray[i] = number + i + 1;
    }

    return testArray;
}
```

or stream

```
public static int[] getValues(int number) {
    return IntStream.range(number + 1, number + 6).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the array declaration works only when declaring a new array.  You can assign to an existing array variable with values in brackets but you have to add new and the type:

```
testArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

It would seem like the type should be inferred but this functionality pre-dates type inference.

Here you can do the declaration once and assign a subrange based on the number passed in:

```
static int[] getValues(int number) {
    if (number > 4 || number < 0) number = 4;
    int[] testArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(testArray, number, number + 5);
}
```

Comment: While this is an elegant way to rewrite the the intended code of the user it doesn't explain nothing related to the problem asked in the question.

Comment: @Davide: true, i added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the syntax `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` only in an initializer (An initializer is the code used to define a new variable and assign to it a value). You need to use the syntax `new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` if you are not using an initializer.

You can refactor your code as follow:

```
public static int[] getValues(int number) {
   switch (number) {
       case 0: return new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}; 
       case 1: return new int[]{2,3,4,5,6}; 
       case 2: return new int[]{3,4,5,6,7}; 
       case 3: return new int[]{4,5,6,7,8}; 
       default: return new int[]{5,6,7,8,9}; 
   }
}
```

Note that I also used a switch that is more readable for this situation. But you can still use an if else if else if you like more.

You can also change the main's method follwing code

```
 int[] newArray = new int[5];
 newArray = getValues(number);
```

to

```
 int[] newArray = getValues(number);
```

infact you don't need to create an empty array that you don't use (new int[5]) and you can directly assign the array returned by the getValues method.